# Printing Tuple's items

Tags: python

I have a list that stored with tuples and I want to print the first item in my tuples

[('RFI', 3704568),
('Le_Figaro', 3590616),
('BFMTV', 3502710),
('libe', 3391929),
('le_Parisien', 3034184),
('Mediapart', 2920291),
('20Minutes', 2535950),
('franceinfo', 2123105),
('Europe1', 1601581),
('lobs', 1519439)]

This is my list and I want to print the text part.

```
for key in top_10_followed:
    top_10_followed_accounts = top_10_followed[key]
    print(top_10_followed_accounts)
```

I wrote that code but I had this error message

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 for key in top_10_followed:
> ----> 2     top_10_followed_accounts = top_10_followed[key]
> 3     print(top_10_followed_accounts)
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Is there any other ways to get the first part of each tuple on my list

Comment: Did you check what is actually contained in `key` variable?

Comment: `for name, number in top_10_followed: print(name)`